# Получение следующей или предшествующей записи из списка по ссылке на текущую запись

Tags: c#, linq, список

Есть свойство `IReadOnlyList<Record> AllRecords` и свойство `Record CurrentRecord`, которое содержит запись из списка `AllRecords`. Как оптимально получить следующую или предыдущую запись в списке?

Comment: Уточните, какой именно список имеет ввиду...

Comment: Вожможно вы неправильно выбрали тип используемой коллекции. Воспользуйтесь LinkedList

Comment: Либо, для оптимального доступа, храните отдельно индекс текущей записи.

Comment: Расскажите вашу задачу более подробно. Откуда у вас `CurrentRecord`?

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от задачи можно либо расширить класс `Record` и хранить в нем ссылки `NextRecord` и `PreviousRecord` на следующий и предыдущий соответственно. (Тогда придется думать над хранением и изменением списка таким образом, чтобы эти ссылки поддерживались в актуальном состоянии)

Либо воспользоваться классом `LinkedList<T>`

```
var records = new LinkedList<Record>();
records.AddLast(record1);
records.AddLast(record2);
```

Тогда для поиска по списку придется проходится по нему через foreach (или воспользоваться методом-расширением - `.ElementAt(n)`, в обоих случаях сложность - O(n)), зато каждый элемент - это LinkedListNode, которая хранит в себе ссылки на предыдущий и следующий элемент.

Если задача предусматривает неизменяемый массив с записями, то можно хранить все элементы в массиве `Record[]` и запоминать индекс полученной записи, тогда очень просто достать соседей по этому индексу.